# How can I fix the error: A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members

Tags: sql-server, mdx, olap

Apologies in advance - I'm not very au fait with MDX

I am wanting to show the previous period variance of a measure.

I’ve tried using the following code in the Cube Calculations section :-

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Analysis Period].[Relative Time].[Previous Period]
AS
    null, 
    VISIBLE = 1;      
SCOPE
(
    [Analysis Period].[Relative Time].[Previous Period],
    [Analysis Period].[Period to Date].ALLMEMBERS
);    
SCOPE
(
   DESCENDANTS (
     [Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].[All],
     [Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Year],
     SELF_AND_AFTER
   )
 );   
THIS = 
(
  [Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].PREVMEMBER,
  [Analysis Period].[Relative Time].&[1]
);    
END SCOPE;    
END SCOPE;    

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Analysis Period].[Relative Time].[Variance PrevPd]
AS
(
  [Analysis Period].[Relative Time].&[1] -
  [Analysis Period].[Relative Time].[Previous Period]
), 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Using the following sample MDX query (generated by the SSMS Browser) :-

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Inflow]} ON COLUMNS
FROM
(
  SELECT
  ( {[Analysis Period].[Relative Time].[Variance PrevPd]} ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM
  (
     SELECT
     ( {[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&[202207]} ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM
     (
       SELECT
       ( {[Fact Type].[Transactions or Holdings].&[Transactions]} ) ON COLUMNS
       FROM [Finscape]
     )
   )
)
WHERE
(
  [Fact Type].[Transactions or Holdings].&[Transactions],
  [Calendar].[Calendar Month].&[202207],
  [Analysis Period].[Relative Time].[Variance PrevPd]
)
```

This returns the error :-

`A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members.`

Google searches indicate that this is related to the use of scope / end scope statements and recommend re-formatting the calculations to remove them – I have tried this, but with everything I tried, I still get the same error.

I’ve now reached the limit of my MDX knowledge and need a steer – can anyone help?